# Every number of heads that is statistically significant in 10 coin flips

Tags: r, statistics

I have this question which I'm not sure how to answer in  a problem sheet I've been given:

"An experimenter is flipping a coin, collecting an initial batch of N=10. If these results are not significant using null hypothesis testing, then she will go on until N=20.

"The significance level is alpha = 0.05, and the coin is fair (p=0.5). What number of heads would be statistically significant for 10 flips of a fair coin?"

"After repeating this for N=20, what combinations of results for N=10 and N=20 are significant?"

I know you can use the dbinom() function to get probabilities, and you can add the probabilities together like so:

```
dbinom(0, 10, 0.5) + dbinom(10, 10, 0.5)  #probability of getting 0 heads and 10 heads for N=10
```

But I'm not sure how to get statistical significance for the number of heads that would be significant? I think that once it is explained to me for N=10, I could likely work out the last two bits of the question, and how do this in R?

Comment: The key here is that the problem states it **is** a fair coin, so you know what the mean and std. dev.  are ahead of time.

Answer (score 2):

Two answer the first part of the question:

`dbinom` will give you the probability density function (pdf), meaning the likelihood of observing a specific outcome of the stochastic experiment.

```
# What's the probability of observing exactly 5 heads when you flip the coin 10 times?
dbinom(5, size=10, p=0.5)
```

You could then plug in all possible values for the first parameter and observe for which outcome your p-threshold is met.

But more elegantly, this is what the cumulative distribution function (cdf) is for. In R, this is implemented for binomial distributions using the `qbinom` function.

```
# Assuming the null-hypothesis,
# what is the number of heads X such that when repeating this experiment

# you will with 95% probability not observe a higher number of heads
qbinom(0.95, size=10, prob=0.5) # X = 8

# or: you will with 95% probability not observe a lower number of heads
qbinom(0.05, size=10, prob=0.5) # X = 2
```

To deepen the understanding, you can then test it reversely:

```
# What's the probability of observing exactly 8 heads when you flip the coin 10 times?
binom(x=8, size=10, prob=.5) # 0.04394531
binom(x=2, size=10, prob=.5) # 0.04394531
```

And as expected, the resulting probability is significant assuming your significance level of 5%.